# Read only the first page of an HTTP served PDF file

Tags: python, pdf

Scenario:
We are interested in fetching the very first page of a PDF available from a remote HTTP server and the application lives in a bandwidth constricted environment.

What are the options to fulfill the task?

Answer (score 0):

The [pyPdf](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/15/manipulating-pdfs-with-python-and-pypdf/) module may help.

Comment: It doesn’t. pyPdf requires a .seek()-able object and in addition to this it looks like pyPdf loads the entire object stream into memory. So I would need to download the entire file first, unless I am missing your point.

Comment: I believe it can read a partial file.  Pulling down only part of the resource is the job of http (do a head request, verify that the remote server accepts ranges, then make a range specific get-request, then run a pdf parser on the result, if a full page wasn't retrieved, then request the next range).

Comment: I opened up a PDF file and reached the object that contains the first page and I deleted from endobj to the end of the file, as if it was a partial file download. pyPdf (and all the cl utilities I have tried so far) complain about a missing %%EOF. Even if I were to add said EOF it would still complain about the missing cross reference table, anyway. It's really harder than I thought.

Comment: Perhaps set up a proxy computer that doesn't live in a bandwidth constrained environment.